# LIO iSCSI Target for Windows Server 2016 Cluster disk - device is not ready

Tags: zfs, high-availability, iscsi, windows-server-2016, windows-cluster

I have a LIO iSCSI Target configured on a Fedora 22 machine exporting 1 LUN to 2 Windows Server 2016 machines, both of these are able to access the disk without issues.

These servers are part of a HA Cluster and when I attempt to add the disk to the cluster, I get the error stating that "the device is not ready". The validation tool says that the storage does not pass because of SCSI-3 Persistent Reservations but from my research, this should give a different error than what I'm receiving.

```
   Creating the physical disk resource for 'Cluster Disk 1'.

Bringing the resource for 'Cluster Disk 1' online.

There was an error creating, configuring, or bringing online the Physical Disk resource (disk) 'Cluster Disk 1'.

The following errors occurred while adding storage to the cluster:

The resource 'Cluster Disk 1' did not come online.

The desired state change for 'Cluster Disk 1' did not occur before the timeout expired.
```

This is my iSCSI Target:

```
o- / ........................................................................................................... [...]
  o- backstores ................................................................................................ [...]
  | o- block .................................................................................... [Storage Objects: 1]
  | | o- ha1 ................................................ [/dev/delta/volpool/ha1 (200.0GiB) write-thru activated]
  | o- fileio ................................................................................... [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- pscsi .................................................................................... [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- ramdisk .................................................................................. [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- user ..................................................................................... [Storage Objects: 0]
  o- iscsi .............................................................................................. [Targets: 1]
  | o- iqn.2017-12.net.hirstgroup.adx.delta:storage.target00 ............................................... [TPGs: 1]
  |   o- tpg1 ................................................................................. [no-gen-acls, no-auth]
  |     o- acls ............................................................................................ [ACLs: 4]
  |     | o- iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:dc1.adx.hirstgroup.net ....................................... [Mapped LUNs: 1]
  |     | | o- mapped_lun0 ..................................................................... [lun0 block/ha1 (rw)]
  |     | o- iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:dc2.adx.hirstgroup.net ....................................... [Mapped LUNs: 1]
  |     | | o- mapped_lun0 ..................................................................... [lun0 block/ha1 (rw)]
  |     | o- iqn.2017-12.net.hirstgroup.adx.dc1:dc1 ................................................. [Mapped LUNs: 1]
  |     | | o- mapped_lun0 ..................................................................... [lun0 block/ha1 (rw)]
  |     | o- iqn.2017-12.net.hirstgroup.adx.delta:iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:dc2.adx.hirstgroup.net .. [Mapped LUNs: 1]
  |     |   o- mapped_lun0 ..................................................................... [lun0 block/ha1 (rw)]
  |     o- luns ............................................................................................ [LUNs: 1]
  |     | o- lun0 ............................................................... [block/ha1 (/dev/delta/volpool/ha1)]
  |     o- portals ...................................................................................... [Portals: 1]
  |       o- 0.0.0.0:3260 ....................................................................................... [OK]
  o- loopback ........................................................................................... [Targets: 0]
  o- vhost .............................................................................................. [Targets: 0]
```

So, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, everything seems to work except the disk will not add to the cluster. One thing I did see in my research is that SCSI-3 Persistant Reservations are required for this to work, but from my understanding LIO does support this. My block device is actually a thin provisioned zvol as I am running ZFS on this machine.

Hopefully someone can help clarify what is going wrong here.

Comment: Sounds risky...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try clearing SCSI-3 Persistent Reservations as LIO could "forget" to update them after LUN ownership changed.

[Clear-ClusterDiskReservation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461016.aspx)

Comment: When I run that command on the disk, I get another 'device is not ready' message. I also removed the volume from the cluster and then tried it, and then re-added the disk to the cluster, no change. I'm not exactly sure where these 'device is not ready' messages are coming from because if I online the disk on the server manually, I can use it without issues.

Comment: If you don't add to the cluster, can you access it keeping in mind only ONE cluster node has established iSCSI connection to your LUN?

Comment: Yes, it works that way without issue, the issue only shows up as soon as I add it to the cluster.

Comment: Make sure you have properly configured LIO. 1) https://blog.jamiebaldanza.org/2012/08/14/ubuntu-12-lio-iscsi-target-configuration/ 2) http://linux-iscsi.org/wiki/Persistent_Reservations

Comment: ...and use SCSIcmd.exe on Windows side to check SCSI-3 PRs are fully functional. 1) https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.TECH72086 2) http://aikitsupport.com/how-to-check-scsi-3-reservation/

Comment: [link](https://snag.gy/3zqbYP.jpg) This is what I get when trying to test Persistent Reservations, my target appears to be configured correctly. I'm not sure exactly what to do from here.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue. It appears that the version of LIO included in Fedora 22 does not correctly support the SCSI-3 Persistent Reservations. I switched to using scsi-target-utils and that worked without issue immediately with this config:

backing-store /blah/blah/blah/zvol
        initiator-address 172.16.20.0/24
        incominguser hgx blahblahblah

Comment: Great! Good luck with your cluster :)